# Как в аиограм создать инлайн кнопку которая при нажатии пишет заготовленый текст в поле для ввода текста?

Tags: python, aiogram, inline

Видел ботов в телеграм у которых есть инлайн кнопка и когда на нее нажимаешь у тебя автоматически вводиться текст в поле для ввода текста "@юзернейм_бота текст", как сделать такие кнопки?

Comment: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton